# Cambiar el nombre de un directorio en un FTP con C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

Paso a detallar mi problema.
Estoy tratando de cambiar el nombre de un directorio/carpeta de un FTP en C#.
En el mismo, lo que hago es, controlo que exista el directorio con el nombre anterior y traigo un booleano (true = existe / false = no existe).
Con este bool, tengo 2 caminos distintos:

- Si no existe, lo creo (esto anda perfecto)
- Si existe, cambio el nombre del directorio al nuevo nombre, acá es donde tengo problema.

El problema que me aparece al intentar cambiar el nombre del directorio es:
"Error en el servidor remoto: (550) Archivo no disponible (ej. no se encuentra el archivo o no se tiene acceso)."

Este es el código que utilizo:

```
public void EditarDirectorioZip(string ruta, string usuario, string pass, string viejo, string nuevo)
    {
        try
        {
            bool banE = ExisteZip(ruta+"/", usuario, pass);

            // Si no existe, la creo
            if (!banE)
            {
                FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ruta + "/");
                ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, pass);
                ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
                ftpReq.Timeout = 10000;
                FtpWebResponse ftpResp = ftpReq.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
                ftpResp.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                // Se conecta al FTP
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ruta);
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, pass);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
                request.RenameTo = nuevo;
                request.Timeout = 10000;

                using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) { }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex) { throw ex; }
    }
```

Busque por todos lados y ninguna solución que me aparecía me sirvió, incluso otras preguntas parecidas en esta misma pagina.

Desde ya muchas gracias a los que les dediquen su tiempo.

Comment: ¿Qué valor estás pasando en la variable `nuevo`?

Comment: es un string conformado por números (ej: nuevo = "123456789";)

Comment: Bien, y en `ruta` ¿estás pasando la ruta completa (incluyendo el nombre del directorio que existe)? Por ejemplo, si el directorio se llama `101`, y suponiendo que su ruta es `ftp://alguna/ruta/hacia`, entonces la variable `ruta` debería ser: `ftp://alguna/ruta/hacia/101`. ¿Es así como lo tienes?

Comment: si si, asi mismo lo tengo

Comment: Lo que queda es que no tengas permisos de escritura sobre ese directorio, por lo cuál recibes el error 550. Tal vez el directorio ha sido creado por otro proceso / usuario y no se han delegado permisos de escritura para el usuario de `ftp`. ¿Has verificado esa posibilidad?

Comment: Si, me fije y tengo todos los permisos de escritura y lectura activados. Igual es raro, porque me deja crear directorios y hacer todo lo que necesito adentro de los mismo (subir y bajar y eliminar archivos)

Comment: Tal vez el directorio está siendo usado por otro proceso o servicio y eso impide su renombrado.

Comment: Cada ves que hago una conexión la cierro ni bien termino de utilizarla. Incluso en las otras zonas del código donde lo uso no me tira errores